# Rails Params Merge in create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller, I need to merge one column that is not there in database. Actually that column name I should not add in db and I should not add migration for this.

This is my create action:

```
   User.new(user_params).merge(first_name: "xyz")
```

This is my user_params method:

```
   def user_params
      params.permit(:id, :name :email_id)
   end
```

but merge is not working. Could any one help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge `first_name` to the params or set it after initiated the `User`

```
def user_params
  params.permit(:id, :name, :email_id).merge(first_name: 'xyz')
end
```

or:

```
user = User.new(user_params)
user.first_name = 'xyz'
```

Edit: If `User` table does not have the `first_name` column you can't do what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use active storage and give relation like user has_one:first_name    and you can add first_name without adding it in your user model/table

```
 def user_params
      params.permit(:id, :name :email_id)
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `merge` for user_params.

```
 User.new(user_params.merge(first_name: "xyz"))
```